# Sorting connected records in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Have Users table, where users can have multiple accounts. 
Table can look like this:

```
u_id | u_parent_d | date_added

1    | 1          | 2017-01-01
2    | 2          | 2017-01-04
3    | 1          | 2017-01-05
4    | 4          | 2017-01-06
5    | 2          | 2017-01-07
```

How can I order these records by date added but grouped connected accounts together

```
u_id | u_parent_d | date_added

5    | 2          | 2017-01-07
2    | 2          | 2017-01-04
4    | 4          | 2017-01-06
3    | 1          | 2017-01-05
1    | 1          | 2017-01-01
```

Comment: Could you add an example output for `grouped connected accounts together`?

Comment: It is added at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your query in two steps. First of all get the maximum date for each `u_parent_d`

```
select   u_parent_d, max(date_added) as max_date
from     Users
group by u_parent_d
```

Then you can join this with the initial table, and use `max_date` for sorting

```
select  t1.*
from    Users t1
join    (
            select   u_parent_d, max(date_added) as max_date
            from     Users
            group by u_parent_d
        ) t2
on      t1.u_parent_d = t2.u_parent_d
order by t2.max_date desc, t1.date_added desc
```

Comment: Maybe `select t1.*` is more close to the expected result in OP.

Answer (score -1):

Order both by date and parent id:

```
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY u_parent_id, date_added DESC
```

Comment: When you get two downvotes, question whether your answer actually answers the question. For instance, would your query provide a result set in the same order as that provided in the question? If you're unsure of the answer to that question, please test before  posting.